# Authenticating with google cloud sdk without service account

Tags: python, authentication, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-sdk

Running from a local jupyter notebook.

I am trying to  do the very simple task of downloading a file from a GCP storage bucket using the following code:

```
from google.cloud import storage

# Initialise a client
storage_client = storage.Client("gcpkey.json")
# Create a bucket object for our bucket
bucket = storage_client.get_bucket("gcp_bucket")
# Create a blob object from the filepath
blob = bucket.blob("file_in_bucket_I_want.file")
# Download the file to a destination
blob.download_to_filename("destination_file_name")
```

Importantly I want to use my end-user account and **cannot** use a service account. I am finding the google [docs](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication#environment-service-accounts) incredibly confusing. Could someone please tell me where to get the gcp json key and whether it is as simple as the code snippet above or whether I have to add some intermediary steps?

When I follow the linked docs I get sent to an OAuth portal and when I login through google I get this error message:

```
This app isn't verified
This app hasn't been verified by Google yet. Only proceed if you know and trust the developer.

If you’re the developer, submit a verification request to remove this screen. Learn more
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest would be to just run

```
gcloud auth application-default login
```

And then in the script just:

```
storage_client = storage.Client()
```

And it will get the credentials from the environment.

Alternatively, you can follow [this doc](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/end-user) to go through the OAuth consent screen and generate a client secret.

Comment: Thank you this was the ridiculously easy solution I was looking for...